# Model from AngularJS to ASP.NET MVC5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, http-post, model-binding

I have some problems posting to my controller from Angular. If i post the variables separately, everything is fine, but when i combine my vars into one object that responds to my view model, it only recognises the ID but not the list of my PlayerViewModel..

Here are my viewModels:

```
public class PlayerViewModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class TeamViewModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public List<PlayerViewModel> Players;
}
```

This is my MVC-controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult IndexPost(int ID, List<PlayerViewModel> ListPlayers, TeamViewModel Team)
    {
        return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

This is my Angular code:

```
$scope.players = [];
            $scope.playerA = { ID: 5, Name: "Player1" };
            $scope.playerB = { ID: 6, Name: "Player2" };
            $scope.playerC = { ID: 8, Name: "Player3" };
            $scope.players.push($scope.playerA);
            $scope.players.push($scope.playerB);
            $scope.players.push($scope.playerC);

            $scope.ID = 7;

            $scope.team = { ID: $scope.ID, Players: $scope.players };

            $scope.btnClick = function () {
                $http({
                    traditional: true,
                    url: "IndexPost",
                    method: "POST",
                    data: { 'ID': $scope.ID, 'ListPlayers': $scope.players, 'Team': $scope.team },
                    dataType: FormData
                }).success(function (data) {
                    $scope.finish = data;
                }).error(function (data) {
                    $scope.status = status;
                });
            }
```

This is my response in the controller:

[(It's an image in dropbox)](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ufys0jrtigyy654/Screenshot%202014-10-27%2015.51.55.png?dl=0)

As you can see, the ID of my TeamViewModel is correct, but the List of PlayerViewModels won't fill in. Does anyone have an idea what i'm doing wrong?

Thank you!!

Comment: I am having the same problem too. You solved the problem?

Comment: Yes, try starting to get an empty model from your backend first, and manipulate that model, instead of making a new JS variable. So start with a HTTP Get, manipulate the model, and then do a HTTP Post. This worked for me..

Answer (score 0):

Serialize your data with [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

```
var data = JSON.stringify({ 'ID': $scope.ID, 'ListPlayers': $scope.players, 'Team': $scope.team });
```

In your original code, you set a js object into the data to send. By serializing it, you send the data as json which your server can read.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this didn't solve my answer when testing. I serialised the data and it looks good, but it won't fill in correctly in mij controller..  This is my serialised string now: "{"ID":7,"ListPlayers":[{"ID":5,"Name":"Player1"},{"ID":6,"Name":"Player2"},{"ID‌​":8,"Name":"Player3"}]}". I only send this var with my httpPost as data but it won't work. Any idea?